# Регистрация роута Laravel

Tags: laravel

Как в Laravel вот этот список роутов

```
Route::get('cab', 'Cab@index');
Route::get('cab/{cab}', 'Cab@show');
```

Превратить в вот это:

```
Cab::routes();
```

По аналогии с Auth::routes()??

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-53-routing-as-authroutes?page=1 И вот еще интересные ответы - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39196968/laravel-5-3-new-authroutes

Comment: Так а как мне создать свой роутлист?

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно в модели Cab создать статический метод ::routes()
И в нем прописать все нужные вам роуты точно также как вы пишите в routes.php или web.php
Вот вам пример кода

```
public static function routes(){
    \Route::get('photos/{size}/{path}/{name}', 'PhotoController@img');
}
```